# What is a use case for resubmitting a pending command buffer in Vulkan

Tags: vulkan

One of the flags for VkCommandBufferBeginInfo is VK_COMMAND_BUFFER_USAGE_SIMULTANEOUS_USE_BIT which the spec describes as

> specifies that a command buffer can be resubmitted to a queue while it is in the pending state, and recorded into multiple primary command buffers.

In my limited experience, I have created separate command buffers for each image in the swapchain since each command buffer is writing to a different framebuffer and consequently I have had no need to try to resubmit a command buffer while it's in the pending state.

What are some use cases for when you would want to set the VK_COMMAND_BUFFER_USAGE_SIMULTANEOUS_USE_BIT flag and resubmit a pending command buffer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature is predominantly for cases where you are rendering a static scene or where differences in rendering are defined by memory operations. Though for even the latter case to apply, you'd have to have some kind of synchronization between the rendering of the last frame, the memory operation, and the rendering of the next one (most memory-only renderers double-buffer the memory, so that one memory object can be read from while another is being modified for the next frame).

Comment: What do you mean by a static scene? Is it related to the “static use” entry in the spec glossary? How does this fix the problem that two of the same command buffer executing simultaneously would be writing to the same framebuffer at the same time?

Comment: @DavidDiGioia: "Pending" does not mean "executing"; it means "pending": to be executed by the GPU at some point, but not yet finished executing. You can use synchronization to prevent writing to the same image at the same time. These could be semaphores or events.